# Define the following environment: \divisorule\begin{flushleft}\end{flushleft}\divisorule

Tags: formatting, environments, line-breaking, environment-variables

Anytimes I need to explain something which could be not clear for someone so that I usually to put it into a shrank text as to follow

```
 \noindent\hrulefill~\raisebox{-4pt}[10pt][10pt]{*any symbol like maltese crux*}~\hrulefill
 \begin{flushleft}
 \leftskip=0.5cm
 \rightskip=0.5cm
 \parindent=0.25cm
 *Any text*
\end{flushleft}
\noindent\hrulefill~\raisebox{-4pt}[10pt][10pt]{*any symbol like maltese crux*}~\hrulefill
```

So to follow I tried to do define a new environment  as to follow.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{report} 

\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{skak}
\usepackage{bbding}

\newcommand{\paperside}[1]{
    \setlength{\leftskip}{#1}
    \setlength{\rightskip}{#1}
}

\newcommand{\normalindent}{\parindent=0.25cm}

\newcommand{\divisorule}[1]{\noindent\hrulefill~\raisebox{-4pt}[10pt][10pt]{#1}~\hrulefill}

\newenvironment{explanation}[1][0cm]{
    \begin{flushleft}
        \paperside{#1}
        \normalindent
    }
    {
    \end{flushleft}
}

\newcommand{\varflushleft}[3]{
    \begin{explanation}[#2]
        \divisorule{#1}\\
        \noindent
        \textmd{
            \normalindent 
            #3}\,\\
        \divisorule{#1}
    \end{explanation}
    }


\begin{document}
    \lipsum[1][1-7]
    
    \varflushleft{\king}{0.5cm}{
        START EXPLANATION 1\\
        \lipsum[1][7-9]\\
        %
        \varflushleft{\queen}{1cm}{
            START EXPLANATION 2\\
            \lipsum[2]\\            
            END EXPLANATION 2
        }
        %
        \lipsum[1][9-10]\\
        END EXPLANATION 1
    }
        
    \lipsum[2][1-5]
\end{document}
```

So the solution I found it is not surely the best since I not really defined a new environment so that to go to a new line in the text I always have to put two slashes: I therefore thought of asking a question here so that I can understand how to actually define an environment with the \varflushleft style which I had difficulty defining since it is not possible to use variables in the closing of a new environment. Could someone help me, please?

**N.B.**

I point out I would like to put the divisor rule outside of flushleft but I was not able to do it.

Comment: what is the intention of `\begin{flushleft}
 \leftskip=0.5cm
 \rightskip=0.5cm
 \parindent=0.25cm`  it is a very strange construct as you set flushleft then undo all its settings so forcing justified, non-flush text?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Actually I used flushleft only because it give some space between the lines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does this fulfill your expectation?

```
\documentclass[10pt]{report} 

\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{skak}
\usepackage{bbding}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\paperside}[1]{%
  \setlength{\leftskip}{#1}%
  \setlength{\rightskip}{\glueexpr #1+\@flushglue\relax}%
}
\makeatother

\newlength{\normalparindent}
\AtBeginDocument{\setlength{\normalparindent}{\parindent}}
\newcommand{\normalindent}{\setlength{\parindent}{\normalparindent}}

\newif\ifnestedexplanation

\newcommand{\divisorule}[1]{%
  \noindent\hrulefill~\raisebox{-4pt}[10pt][10pt]{#1}~\hrulefill
}

\NewDocumentEnvironment{explanation}{mO{0cm}}{%
  \par
  \nestedexplanationtrue
  \raggedright
  \paperside{#2}%
  \normalindent
  \divisorule{#1}\par\nopagebreak
}{
  \par\nopagebreak
  \divisorule{#1}\par
}
\AddToHook{env/explanation/after}{%
  \ifnestedexplanation\else\addvspace{\topsep}\fi
}
\AddToHook{env/explanation/before}{%
  \par\ifnestedexplanation\else\addvspace{\topsep}\fi
}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1][1-7]
    
\begin{explanation}{\king}[0.5cm]
  \lipsum[1][7-9]

  \begin{explanation}{\queen}[1cm]
    \lipsum[2]          
  \end{explanation}

  \lipsum[1][9-10]
\end{explanation}
        
\lipsum[2][1-5]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Some vertical space is added before and after the outer explanation, but not around nested ones. The `\nopagebreak` commands ensure that no page break can happen after the starting ornamentation or before the closing one.

Without indentation of the first explanation paragraph and justification. Also the ornamentation is made optional, but then the margin amount has to be specified differently.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{report} 

\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{skak}
\usepackage{bbding}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\paperside}[1]{%
  \setlength{\leftskip}{#1}%
  \setlength{\rightskip}{#1}%
}

\newlength{\normalparindent}
\AtBeginDocument{\setlength{\normalparindent}{\parindent}}
\newcommand{\normalindent}{\setlength{\parindent}{\normalparindent}}

\newif\ifnestedexplanation

\newcommand{\divisorule}[1]{%
  \noindent\hrulefill~\raisebox{-0.7ex}[10pt][10pt]{#1}~\hrulefill
}

\NewDocumentEnvironment{explanation}{O{\maltese}D<>{0cm}}{%
  \par
  \nestedexplanationtrue
  \paperside{#2}%
  \divisorule{#1}\par\@afterheading\@afterindentfalse
}{
  \par\nopagebreak
  \divisorule{#1}\par
}
\AddToHook{env/explanation/after}{%
  \ifnestedexplanation\else\addvspace{\topsep}\fi
}
\AddToHook{env/explanation/before}{%
  \par\ifnestedexplanation\else\addvspace{\topsep}\fi
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1][1-7]
    
\begin{explanation}[\king]<1cm>
  \lipsum[1][7-9]

  \begin{explanation}<2cm>
    \lipsum[2][1-3]

    \lipsum[2][4-6]
  \end{explanation}

  \lipsum[1][9-10]
\end{explanation}
        
\lipsum[2][1-5]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The code seems to work fine: thanks really for the nice answer! Only two last requirements, provided it's no too boring: actually, I would like first line (just only the first) was not indented; moreover, I would like to set the maltese cross (\maltese) as default value for ornament on separation line, provided it's possible. Thanks in advance. :-)

P.S.

Actually I do not really know if I originally used flushleft to give some space: indeed, reflecting about I concluded I use it only to separate the explanation by the normal text; however I think it seems appropriate to give a bit space.

Comment: It seems I can suppress the indentation on first line by adding the sequence command "\noindent\ignorespaces" after the first "\divisorule{#1}\par\nopagebreak" line, right?

Comment: @AntonioMariaDiMauro I added an alternative version along the specified lines.

Comment: I just implemented your code in mine: it works perfectly except for the lists (bulleted and numbered) within which I have to specify the new indentation, but it doesn't matter much. I thank you very much for your help: question approved and upvoted. Thanks again :-)

Comment: @AntonioMariaDiMauro Oh, yes! Lists work bad when there's a nonzero outer `\leftskip` or `\rightskip`.

Comment: That's no problem: after all, it's easily fixable by indicating a new margin value with paperside command. ;-)